# Knockout 3.2 - 'if' based transition between AMD loaded components

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-components

I have an SPA that uses knockout components dynamically loaded with require.

Here is what it currently looks like

```
        <!-- ko if: state() === 'one' -->
        <component-one></component-one>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: state() === 'two' -->
        <component-two></component-two>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: state() === 'three' -->
        <component-three params="myParam: MyParam()"></component-three>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: state() === 'four' -->
        <component-four></component-four>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

What I'm looking for is something that produces the same result as the `if` binding for virtual elements but also allows me to place a transition (fade in/ out) when the state changes.

I have found something like this http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kNtdu/ which appears to work for knockout 2.1 but not 3.2.

Please note I'm not looking for just a `fadeVisible`, but more along the lines of a `fadeIf`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a binding that I just put together.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ifFading = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, ignored1, ignored2, bindingContext) {
        var template = $(ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element)).filter("*").clone(),
            lastValue = false;
        ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(element);

        ko.computed(function () {
            var dataValue = !!ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            if (dataValue !== lastValue) {
                lastValue = dataValue;
                if (dataValue) {
                    var templateClone = template.clone();
                    ko.virtualElements.setDomNodeChildren(element, templateClone);
                    templateClone.hide();
                    ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
                    templateClone.fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $(ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element)).fadeOut(function () {
                        ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(element);
                    });
                }
            }
        }, null, { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element });

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.ifFading = true;
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/6tpn5uhy/

Here's a simpler version that doesn't use `fadeOut`: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/6tpn5uhy/1/

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks for your help. Note at the end of your snippet in the answer should read allowedBindings.ifFading instead of allowedBindings.ifSliding. I also added a delay at templateClone.delay(400).fadeIn(); in order to stop the elements overlapping.

Comment: As an improvement - I am using requirejs which fetches the component when needed so the first load of the component has a little latency which means the element fades in before the component is loaded, causing it to pop in. Is there a way to fade in after the components child elements have fully bound?

Comment: There isn't a way for this binding to know when the component has loaded. Instead, you'd have to include the fade-in logic within the component template or pre-load the components.

Comment: I modified a "with"-style binding for this. Actually the logic could be simpler because an "if"-style doesn't need to rebind.